# Calendar By Weeks

Tags: excel, calendar

Is it possible in Ms Excel to generate the calendar of current year By weeks,
example:

```
week - Start day - End day 
S1    01/01/2018 - 07/01/2018
S2
S3
...
```

Comment: What day is the end of week?

Comment: I suggest using one of the official templates - https://templates.office.com/en-us/Calendars

Comment: @PaichengWu , sunday

Comment: @M.Douda ,  thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
A2 : 1
B2 : define the 1st day 
C2 : =B2+7
at A3 : = A2+1
at B3 : = B2+7
at C3 : = C2+7
```

select A3:C3 then drag it downward.

r-click > format > date for colum B,C

Please study weeknum() & date() function in the excel help. it can be also used to generate your desired dates/format.

Hope that helps. (:

Comment: it works  thank you very much!